# Are you able to find me in second(s)?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Found somewhere in Peru,
>   I am well behaved and follow the queue.
>
> Flipped from the left to right,
>   In a name to the children's like.
>
> Switch places with you and me,
>   A comfort place becomes a wild beast.
>
> How many times have I shown my face?
>   All you need is a little trace!

**What am I?**

Comment: It may be Andes Mountain (Machu Picchu) or Amazon rainforest, not sure?

Comment: @CR241 nope, that will only fits with the first line.  Keep trying!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Thanks to [M Oehm](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9860/m-oehm) for solving the final stanza, and [Erel Segal-Halevi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/7315/erel-segal-halevi) for solving the title.

I think you are

> The letter R

### Are you able to find me in second(s)?

> R is the second letter of the title (Thanks [Erel Segal-Halevi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/7315/erel-segal-halevi))

*Found somewhere in Peru,*

> R is the third letter of Pe**r**u

*I am well behaved and follow the queue.*

> R is the letter after Q

*Flipped from the left to right,

In a name to the children's like.*

> The logo of 'Toys "R" Us', a toy store, has a flipped R in its logo

*Switch places with you and me,

A comfort place becomes a wild beast.*

> Ho**u**se becomes ho**r**se

*How many times have I shown my face?

All you need is a little trace!*

> When the Rs in the riddle are connected, an R apppears (thanks [M Oehm](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9860/m-oehm))
> [image: Trace]

**What am I?**

> What **R** you?

Comment: Very good, I think that's it. As to the last stanza: Maybe it's a bit of a stretch, but if you connect the seven Rs in the poem, you get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fum6I.png).

Comment: @MOehm wow that is pretty clever

Comment: "Switch places with you and me" -> you "are" me (and me is you). Doesnt this mean pretending to be someone else so the "switching places" line is a seperate clue?

Comment: @TotumusMaximus Not sure, I'm pretty sure it means to swap "u" with me ("r") in a word (house)

Comment: I think comfort place part requires finding a word where both U (you) and M (me) get replaced with R to spell a wild beast. And I wouldn't call horse a wild beast - not all that many wild horses are still left, and majority would first think of the domestic one.

Comment: The title is still unsolved. Maybe 'second(s)' is a synonym of 'dessert' in British English, so there's an 'r' in that word. Only thing I can think of.

Comment: R is the second letter of the title.

Comment: @ZizyArcher Not too sure about that, "you" is a homophone of "u" but "me" is not a homophone of "m"

Comment: Really cool thinking, and the reasoning looks good.

Comment: Awesome!  Also really like it when everyone put in the effort for all hints!

Comment: @ZizyArcher Could've used "majestic" beast instead of wild beast, but horses does belongs to the wild!

Answer (score 5):

I think you are

> the letter E.

*Are you able to find me in second(s)?*

> E is the **second** letter of the word "second".

*Found somewhere in Peru,*

> ... and the second letter of "Peru" ...

*I am well behaved and follow the queue.*

> ... and the last letter of "queue".

*Flipped from the left to right,

In a name to the children's like.*

> Maybe ∃ (the existence symbol) is somehow associated with children?

*Switch places with you and me,

A comfort place becomes a wild beast.*

> I'm guessing this means there's a word meaning a place of comfort which, when its U ("you") becomes an E, turns into a word meaning a wild beast.

*How many times have I shown my face?

All you need is a little trace!*

> Quite a few times in this riddle, and indeed in most pieces of English writing.

Comment: So close, and will work if you found a way to fit in line 5&6.  Actually there's another riddle about the letter E, right when I posted mine (it's gone now for some reason).